# Is there a way to annotate an AutoBean property so that it will not be serialized/deserialized?

Tags: gwt, autobean

I have an autobean with a property that is only needed for the UI. I believe that you can null out values and the `AutoBeanCodex` will not serialized that property, but that equates to an extra step which is needed at serialization.

I was hoping for some annotation similar to the `Editor` `@Ignore` annotation. For example:

```
public interface Foo {
    ...
    @Ignore
    String getUiOnlyProperty();
}
```

So, other than nulling out the value at serialization time, is there any other way to keep an autobean property from being serialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autobeans are meant to be a Java skin on a JSON/XML/whatever format - they aren't really designed to hold other pieces of data. That said, several thoughts that either nearly answer your question with out-of-the-box tools, or might inspire some other ideas on how to solve your problem.

You should be able to build read-only properties by omitting the setter. This isn't quite what you are asking for, but still might be handy.

Along those lines, the JavaDoc for the `@PropertyName` annotation seems to allude to this possible feature:

```
/**
 * An annotation that allows inferred property names to be overridden.
 * <p>
 * This annotation is asymmetric, applying it to a getter will not affect the
 * setter. The asymmetry allows existing users of an interface to read old
 * {@link AutoBeanCodex} messages, but write new ones.
 */
```

Reading old messages but writing new ones seems like it might be closer to what you are after, and still allowing you to work with the thing-that-looks-like-a-bean.

The real answer though seems to be the `AutoBean.setTag` and `getTag` methods:

```
/**
 * A tag is an arbitrary piece of external metadata to be associated with the
 * wrapped value.
 * 
 * @param tagName the tag name
 * @param value the wrapped value
 * @see #getTag(String)
 */
void setTag(String tagName, Object value);
```

...

```
/**
 * Retrieve a tag value that was previously provided to
 * {@link #setTag(String, Object)}.
 * 
 * @param tagName the tag name
 * @return the tag value
 * @see #setTag(String, Object)
 */
<Q> Q getTag(String tagName);
```

As can be seen from the implementation of these methods in `AbstractAutoBean`, these store their data in a totally separate object from what is sent over the wire. The downside is that you'll need to get the underlying AutoBean object (see `com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBeanUtils.getAutoBean(U)` for one way to do this) in order to invoke these methods.

Comment: I completely overlooked the get/setTag. That could work.

But what if I had an interface `FooRaw` which `Foo` extended? Then, I could decode on `Foo.class`, but encode on `FooRaw.class`.

I haven't tried it, but that _should_ only encode the properties defined in `FooRaw`, right?

Comment: You'll probably need to have an intermediate Splittable between those types or something - you don't specify a type to the AutoBeanCodex.encode method, it just takes the autobean. The autobean contains the type details already - it knows what type it represents.

Comment: Well, this is a good set of options to play with. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

child class/interface decoded as a parent interface does not explode on decoding allowing the goods to be passed together before the marshalling steps.  my immediate test of the actual code below is performing as expected.

```
  public interface ReplicateOptions {
    /**
     * Create target database if it does not exist. Only for server replications.
     */
    Boolean getCreateTarget();

    void setCreateTarget(Boolean create_target); 

  //baggage to pass along
  interface ReplicateCall<T> extends ReplicateOptions   {

      /**
       * If true starts subscribing to future changes in the source database and continue replicating them.
       */
      AsyncCallback<T> getContinuous();

      void setContinuous(AsyncCallback<T> continuous); 

}
}
```